# Installing Disqus for flask-flatpages blog

Tags: flask, markdown, jinja2, disqus

I'm trying to use Disqus for the commenting platform for a blogging website I made using Flask and Flask-flatpages.

I am running into the issue where I'm trying to use Jinja2 variables as the commenting page identifier (for disqus) to have separate comment threads for separate posts but I'm failing to do so. I can't get disqus to work separately for each post and have a working comment counter also.

I have my blog set up so that I have markdown pages (.md) for my blog posts and I render the posts using python markdown into `post.html` which looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html %}
{% block content %}

..lines of code..
{{ blog }} //var name for my blog posts

<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/**
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
/*
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
*/
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = '//EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>

<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//EXAMPLE.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Is this the correct way to embed the Disqus Universal Code? If so, how do I pass Jinja2 variables (i.e. `{{ blog.meta.id}}` ) as the JS identifier varaible?

Thanks

Comment: Is this your actual code? You've got an obvious quote error on the very first line.

Comment: oh, that's a typo on my part. I think it eventually worked though, it needed 10-20 minutes for the JS to run properly though.